# Error opening SigmaPlot: "the specified macro default library cannot be opened"

Tags: sigmaplot

I use [sigmaplot](/questions/tagged/sigmaplot) ver. 10.0.  It was working before but now it has some problem.

When I start SigmaPlot I see:

> The specified macro default library can not be opened. Please make sure it is a valid notebook or select another from Tools/Options/Macro.

pop up, but it works well. However, when I type F5 (to use regression wizard), I see:

> The equation library file 
>    C\User\Stealth\Documents\Sigmaplot\SPW10\STANDARD.JFL
>   cannot be used because of the file's permissions attributes
>   (such as Read Only restrictions)

and there are no regression options (such as gaussian, linear, etc...).  The same phenomenon occurs running as administrator.  What am I doing wrong? help me please...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with SigmaPlot14. It turned out that OneNote moved all folders from `C/user/documents...` to `C/user/Onenote/documents...`.

I manually copied all folders back to the  `C/user/documents...` folder and this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can also just edit the settings .ini file so that the it points to the correct folders.